# node-inspector shows 'No Properties' for objects

Tags: node.js, debugging, node-inspector

I'm pretty new in the debugging scene, especially with node-inspecor.

After I had installed node-inspector, I started my simple node app with the --debug parameter and was able to see the debug view at localhost:8080/debug?port=5858.

When I let the app stop at this breakpoint:

```
router.get('/people', function(req, res) {
    var num = 1;
    var str = 'rarf';
    var obj = {x: 1, y: 2}

    console.log(req)    // breakpoint
});
```

and hover with the curser on the identifier, it shows as follows:

- req: **Incoming Message** - No Properties
- res: **Server Response** - No Properties
- str: "rarf"
- num: 1
- obj: **Object** - No Properties

Why can't I see the properties of objects?

Comment: `req` and `res` are only defined WITHIN a specific route handler (they are arguments to that handler function). If you set the breakpoint inside the route handler, then you should be able to inspect the values of req and res. You don't show where you are setting the breakpoint since `var x = 'hello'` isn't in your code snippet.

Comment: I added x= 'hello' to the snippet

Comment: Then, you're not doing something correctly in node-inspector if you can't see the values of `req` and `res` from a breakpoint on the `hello` line of code.  I have no idea what the issue is though from this little bit of information.  Can you see the values of any variables in node-inspector?

Comment: My experience with viewing large objects in node-inspector is that it is sometimes slow.  Because it's a different process and sometimes even on a different computer, the property values have to be fetched remotely before being displayed.  Try making a Watch Expression for `req` and then have some patience and see if the value shows up.  You can also look at what properties to expect on those objects at a [reference like this one](http://www.murvinlai.com/req-and-res-in-nodejs.html) and then create a Watch Expression for the values of individual properties you want to see.

Comment: What version of Node Inspector and Node.js are you using?

Comment: node v0.10.35, node-inspector@0.8.1

Comment: Now I have reinstalled node-inspector and got this warning during the installation: `gyp WARN EACCES user "root" does not have permission to access the dev dir "/home/x/.node-gyp/0.10.35"
gyp WARN EACCES attempting to reinstall using temporary dev dir "/usr/lib/node_modules/node-inspector/node_modules/v8-profiler/.node-gyp"` But nothing has changed

Comment: Having the same issue.  I found if you open the javascript console and type console.log(theobject) you can then drill into its properties.  I did it doesn't give me all the functions I know are there but seems a tad more helpful then nothing.

Comment: 0.10.35 is a bad version for debugging. Downgrade to 0.10.33 or vait 0.10.36 (https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector/issues/461), but all this is not reasonable to your main problem. How about update to 0.8.3 and try again.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. my node version is 0.10.35(stable). But when I use the node version `0.11.13(unstable)` or later, this problem is gone. So, you would try to update your node version to `0.11.13` that use the tools **`n`**. Use the `npm install -g n` command to install the `n`.

Comment: I updated node to v0.11.13 but the problem still remains. Thanks anyway