# Node-Inspector debugger Runtime.getProperties failed. Can't see values of variables

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-inspector

[image]I must be missing something really basic here but I am not seeing the values of variables inside or outside of functions using node-inspector.

UPDATE: I am on node --version -> v0.10.35
Also I think maybe someone else has similar problem without an answer yet :

[node-inspector shows 'No Properties' for objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27830963/node-inspector-shows-no-properties-for-objects?rq=1)

I am seeing the same as this error:

Runtime.getProperties failed. ReferenceError: includeSource is not defined #461
https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector/issues/461
Is this still an issue? I just 'npm installed node-inspector' 0.8.3 and downloaded chrome Version 39.0.2171.65 (64-bit), but I cannot see the values of variables.

I have a simple javascript program called test.js

```
         var test1 = 'test';
         debugger;
         console.log(test1);
```

Then I run:

```
 node --debug-brk test.js
```

Followed by:

node-inspector
Node Inspector v0.8.3
Visit http://127.0.0.1:8080/debug?port=5858 to start debugging.

breaking on line 1,2 or 3 and I always see this error.  No values shown for the variables variables.  I also found this to be the case inside functions.

Comment: am I the only one using node-inspector? where is everyone?

Answer (score 0):

That issue number (#461) you referenced is correct, you either have to downgrade node itself to <=0.10.33 or >=0.10.36. I personally had some problems with 0.10.36, but node-inspector is working for me again in 0.10.37.

In addition, you can use [Node Version Manager](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) to quickly install and switch between several versions of node.